# Adding Children Nodes to a Tree in Python

Tags: python, tree, breadth-first-search

I am trying to create a tree in python, which I want to be able to do a breadth first traversal later on. However, when I try to loop through the children of a node (i.e the root), it doesn't seem to find any children. However, if I try to access the child separately (root.children[1]) it is valid. I am pretty sure I am doing something silly, but I am not sure where. Here is my code:

```
class Component:
    def __init__(self, compName, originName, connected = False): #removed to decrease code size
    def __str__(self):
        return "\n\tComponent Name: {0}\n\tOrigin Name: {1}\n\tConnected: {2}\n".format(self.name, self.origin, str(self.connected));

class Node:
    def __init__(self, component, parent):
        self.children = [];    
    def add_node(self, node):       
        self.children.append(node);
        #...left out some broken code that is commented out...#
    def __str__(self):
        return "{0}".format(str(self.component));

class Tree:
    def __init__(self):
    def add_component(self, component, parent = None):
        if self.root is None:
            self.root = Node(component, parent);
        else:
            self.root.add_node(Node(component, parent));

def breadth_first(node):
    result = [];
    queue = [];
    queue.append(node);

    while queue:
        node = queue.pop(0);
        result.append(node);
        plog("Adding to result\n");
        plog(str(node));

        if node in node.children:
            for child in node.children:
                if child not in result and child not in queue:
                    queue.append(child);
        else:
            plog("NO CHILDREN\n");  // this is being displayed
    return result;

def main(ScriptArgument, oDesktop):
    component = Component("Laminate", "B7_TX");
    tree = Tree();
    tree.add_component(component);

    component = Component("B7", "B7_TX");
    tree.add_component(component, "Laminate");

    result = breadth_first(tree.root);
    for x in result:
        plog(str(x) + "\n");
```

This is the output I am getting:

```
Adding to result           # output from breadth-first

Component Name: Laminate   #output from breadth-first
Origin Name: B7_TX
Connected: False
NO CHILDREN                # this is indicating that the child was not added properly, I believe

Component Name: Laminate   # output from the loop in main
Origin Name: B7_TX
Connected: False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you checking if the parent is in the list of children with the following line?

```
if node in node.children:
```

I would simply do:

```
[...]
while queue:
    node = queue.pop(0);
    result.append(node);
    plog("Adding to result\n");
    plog(str(node));

    for child in node.children:
        if child not in result and child not in queue:
            queue.append(child);
return result;
```

Answer (score 0):

My "if" check was wrong. I was checking to see if the root (or current) node is in its own children list, which was wrong. I simply changed this to check if there are any children (if node.children:) and it worked.